# Prevent /home folder from being mounted up

Tags: 14.04, mount, mountpoint

In my system, a user can mount a device to a directory. I want to prevent user from mounting device to `/home` directory using `mount` command.

What is the way to disallow mounting to a specific folder?

Comment: Without root, I don't think they can mount to `/home` so what is the problem?

Comment: I have faced this issue as some user has mounted /home directory.

Comment: With root? Because then I think there is not much you can do...

Comment: Yes. With root.